# Trigger Botframework v4 on Facebook Messenger from an external website call

Tags: facebook, botframework, facebook-messenger, direct-line-botframework

i am trying to open a specific messenger page and trigger a dialog to display carousels based on the parameters that my users entered on my website. 
i am leveraging the m.me link to open my messenger page (where my botframeowrk bot is deployed). After opening the page I am not able to invoke a dialog.

How can I achieve this ???

I went through the Ms Botframework V4 docs and didn't find any mention of channel specific trigger.I want to pass 4 parameters to my Bot from the website and then further make an api call in the dialog that i will invoke to display results.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using C# since your last bot question was also C#. Is that correct? Also, did the user open the original web page through a URL in the bot or are you trying to have the carousal send as a welcome message once the user gets directed to your bot from the original website?

Comment: yes...c#..and yes i want  have the carousal sent as a welcome message once the user gets directed to my bot from the original website.

Comment: @tdurnford..i am using c# botframework v4. Earlier i was using converse..there i could easily pass in parameters from the webpage to my messenger bot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Messaging Referrals in the Facebook Developer portal to use m.me links. In the portal, click on the settings blade on the left, scroll down to webhooks, and click edit events. A window should pop up where you can enable `messaging_referrals`.

[image]

Facebook only lets you add the `ref` parameter to the m.me link, so to send additional data to the bot using this link, you will have to encode the values in the ref parameter and parse the data on the bot side - I would recommend using a separator value like a comma or a slash to organize your data.

`https://m.me/<PAGE_NAME>?ref=my,additional,data`

The event will be send to the bot as a message activity with a referral attribute where you can grab your data.

**m.me link bot activity**

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "id": "CDbQi3u62J7",
  "timestamp": "2019-03-19T19:30:11.219Z",
  "serviceUrl": "https://facebook.botframework.com/",
  "channelId": "facebook",
  "from": {
    "id": "2031650190235097",
    "name": "TJ Durnford"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "isGroup": false,
    "id": "2031650190235097-218838049015546"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "218838049015546",
    "name": "thdurn-all-channels"
  },
  "channelData": {
    "sender": {
      "id": "2031650190235097"
    },
    "recipient": {
      "id": "218838049015546"
    },
    "timestamp": 1553023811219,
    "referral": {
      "ref": "my,additional,data",
      "source": "SHORTLINK",
      "type": "OPEN_THREAD"
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps!